# How do I circumvent the "Your connection is not private" error

Tags: google-chrome

For school, I sometimes need to go to third party websites for audio books for class. A lot of the YouTube ones are restricted, so I try to find ones on third party sites. I then get an error saying "Your connection is not private".

How can I tell Google Chrome or the school wifi that I don't care that my connection is not private? I don't have super secret data or passwords. I am just some random student, why would any attacker target me? And since I don't have any important info, what is the worst they could do? How can I make it clear that I don't care how private my connection is?

Comment: Give a site example URL for where this is occurring @Asadefa. Just one example should suffice

Comment: The error is to warn you that there is an issue with the site's SSL cert, of which, on a site with malicious content, can result in MITM attacks and a whole host of other attacks.  This is extremely important if you're downloading content from the site, entering login info for the site, or auto-fill data.  There's no way to know without providing site examples.

Comment: "why would any attacker target me?"

They want your computer to either use as part of a bot net, or to use in spreading their malware so it will eventually get to a mchine that is useful to them.

Comment: If only a certificate problem... you may add specific exceptions. Have you tried [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/)? [Here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) you can read more. BTW single questions are preferred (read [ask]). In general even if you do not have NOW sensible data you may have it IN FUTURE, or from friends that occasionally use your computer. The worst? Anything you can think but worst...all with your name. (leaked photos/chat of persons you know, bank transaction, fraud, ending up with really really bad things, both with good or evil intentions)

Answer (score 13):

As of Chrome 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Windows, if you type `thisisunsafe` on the error page (not into any textbox, just blindly while the page has focus), it will do the equivalent of clicking the no-longer-existing "Proceed" link. This is probably the best solution for now if you're using Chrome.

Comment: I can't believe this works and how long it took to find it. I'm really against this method of 'nanny protection' .

Answer (score 6):

Simply enable this option: Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost, from chrome://flags, you can quickly tells Google Chrome from accepting self-signed SSL certificate and get rid of this issue.

Source: https://bytebitebit.com/687/your-connection-is-not-private/

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with one site I know that has a bad certificate: https://utox.io/

It has been impossible to force the latest Chrome and Firefox browsers to accept
its certificate, as both browsers have lately considerably hardened their
certificate acceptance rules.
<s>Chrome had until lately the parameter `ignore-certificate-errors`,
but even that has been suppressed.</s>
Even Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 absolutely refuse that website.

I can't see another solution than finding a browser that is less strict than
the above four browsers, and that you can force to accept bad certificates.

For example, I have tested
[Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/)
which is a fork of Firefox that still accepts the legacy add-on format.
Although Pale Moon routinely includes security updates from Firefox,
it has not (yet?) hardened its certificate handling to that degree.
Pale Moon still gives in its certificate error message the option of
"I Understand the Risks", where you can choose the option of
"Add Exception..." that will allow accepting that certificate either
permanently or temporarily.

EDIT: User benrg in a comment below describes an undocumented feature
in Chrome that allows accessing websites with invalid certificates.

The trick is to type blindly into the error page the characters
`thisisunsafe`. Chrome will then display the website and accept the
certificate. The display of the website will in this case include the
indication of "Not secure":

[image]

Comment: Does Pale Moon support Linux

Comment: Yes it does have a Linux version.

Comment: Chromium (or some older version of it) might also still support the parameter of `ignore-certificate-errors`, but I haven't tested it. I would prefer instead the ability to choose the websites to ignore, as is the case with Pale Moon or other forks.

Comment: @Asadefa: It seems as though you are suspended from our site and cannot answer.

Comment: `--ignore-certificate-errors` still works as of Chrome 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Windows, but it completely eliminates the warning page for all sites, so it's rather dangerous. It still shows "not secure" in the address bar, so it may be okay if you're careful about always checking that. Another solution is to type `thisisunsafe` on the error page (not into any textbox, just blindly while the page has focus). That will do the equivalent of clicking the no-longer-existing "Proceed" link. I just tested both of these on `utox.io` and they seem to work.

Comment: @benrg: Good news, I also verify that `--ignore-certificate-errors` is now working again. Answer updated (at least for now).

Comment: I also do not recommend the `--ignore-certificate-errors` parameter of Chrome as being too dangerous, running the Web without any warning of fake websites.